# backbone.js collection view inside collection view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a table of entries(=collection) with columns - **activity, name, rate, hours**

now **activity** is a selectbox with options(=another collection?), futher more, rate should be copied from attribute of currently selected option..

How can I inject(?) those options to the template of the first collection? Especially when rendering of the first collection needs attributes from the other collection(rate).

I also don't want to have each inside each, since those options are always the same and the selected parameters can be set later with javascript.

// edit
actually never mind the needs to copy rates from selectbox, I had to do it like this before I started trying to convert it to backbone

on the other hand, I'm still gonna need it on change..

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide a jsfiddle or equiv? It's difficult to understand what you're looking for here given how little information you provided.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I have so far settled on passing all data to just one view, but I'm not sure if that's the right way, nor if I actually won't need what I asked for. Anyway here's jsbin http://jsbin.com/igajer/1

What I'd want is to have a separeted view for activitiesCollection and peopleCollection, and not have _.each for activities/people inside _.each for entries

Comment: underscore has templates that you could use

Comment: What I've done... you could pass in other template instances to the outer templates and use `<% print(templates['named-template'](objects)) >%` to output the reusable template content.

Comment: Can the activity just be a static list or does it have to be a Collection?

Comment: Thought about that too, but then again, there might be another place where I could need the list to be a Collection. I think.

Comment: You can get by without a Collection if you don't need the extra functions that comes with a Collection. You can always keep adding property to a list and make it as a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that you can try. I'm still not 100% on what your objective is but I have a feeling that you're trying to solve an issue in a much complicated angle than necessary.

**View:**

```
var EntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  /** Get the values from the view elements. */
  serialize: function() {
    return {
      activity: this.$('.activity :selected').val(),
      person: this.$('.person :selected').val(),
      budget: this.$('.budget').val()
    }
  },
  events:{
      'change .test': 'changeActivity'
    },
  changeActivity: function(ev) {
     /** Event is triggered when any of the select element changes. */
     var entry = this.serialize();
     console.log(entry);
  }, ...
```

On your template, I added an extra class on each element to distinguish them from each other.

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_entries">
<% _.each(entries, function(entry) { %>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <select class="activity test">                              
       <% _.each(activities, function(activity) { %>                                
          <option><%= activity.get('name') %></option>
       <% }); %>
    </select>
    </td>
        <td>
    <select class="person test">
      <% _.each(people, function(person) { %>
           <option><%= person.get('name') %></option>
      <% }); %>
    </select>
    </td>
        <td>
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="budget input-small" type="text" 
                   value="<%= entry.get('budgeted') %>" /> ...
```

Hope this helps and leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what my objective was either, my question resulted from a absolute lack of knowledge of how backbone works. Thanks anyway!